# swig typemap from c++ struct to PyLong

Tags: c++, struct, swig

I'm trying to create a typemap from a C++ struct to a PyLong.

For example, I have the following struct that represents a 128 bit number, and I would like to access it in the Python interface as a simple Python unsigned long.

```
struct my_128 {
    u_int64_t raw[2];
};
```

How can I create such a typemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent full error checking, these typemaps work:

```
%typemap(in) struct my_128 {
    PyObject* temp;
    PyObject* shift;
    if(!PyLong_Check($input) && !PyInt_Check($input))
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Must be int or long type");
        return NULL;
    }
    $1.raw[0] = PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLongMask($input); // low 64-bits
    shift = PyInt_FromLong(64);
    temp = PyNumber_Rshift($input,shift);
    $1.raw[1] = PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLongMask(temp);   // high 64-bits
    Py_DECREF(temp);
    Py_DECREF(shift);
}

%typemap(out) struct my_128 {
    PyObject* low;
    PyObject* high;
    PyObject* shift;
    PyObject* intermediate;
    low = PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong($1.raw[0]);
    high = PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong($1.raw[1]);
    shift = PyInt_FromLong(64);
    intermediate = PyNumber_Lshift(high,shift);
    $result = PyNumber_Add(low,intermediate);
    Py_DECREF(low);
    Py_DECREF(high);
    Py_DECREF(intermediate);
    Py_DECREF(shift);
}
```

Comment: +1, that's far nicer than my solution - I was missing the `PyNumber` functions

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works, but it's not pretty. The problem is it seems the only way to make a PyLong from C that's longer than `long long` [is with a string](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/long.html)!

So for a typemap that takes your `my_128` and exposes it as a PyLong when it's returned from a function you can do:

```
%typemap(out) my_128 {
  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "0x"
    << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << $1.raw[0]
    << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << $1.raw[1];
  char *c = strdupa(s.str().c_str()); // Avoids a const cast without leaking ever
  $result = PyLong_FromString(c,0,0);
}
```

Which prints it in hex to a `stringstream` and then constructs a PyLong from that.

The corresponding typemap going the other way is even uglier. We need to take our PyLong and persuade python to convert it to a suitable string by calling the builtin `hex()` on it.

Then we need to massage that into something that we can read from (two) `stringstreams` (otherwise the first one steals all the input). This ends up looking like:

```
%typemap(in) my_128 {
  PyObject *moduleName = PyString_FromString((char*)"__builtin__");
  assert(moduleName);
  PyObject *module = PyImport_Import(moduleName);
  assert(module);

  PyObject *hex = PyObject_GetAttrString(module,(char*)"hex");
  assert(hex);
  PyObject *args = PyTuple_Pack(1,$input);
  assert(args);
  PyObject *result = PyObject_CallObject(hex, args);
  assert(result);
  std::string str(PyString_AsString(result));
  if (str.find("0x")!=std::string::npos) {
    str=str.substr(2);
  }
  if (str.find("L") != std::string::npos) {
    str=str.substr(0,str.size()-1);
  }
  assert(str.size());
  if (str.size() > 16) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected at most a 128-bit int");
    return NULL;
  }
    std::istringstream s1(str.substr(0,8));
    if (!(s1 >> std::hex >> $1.raw[0])) {
      $1.raw[0]=0;
    }
    std::istringstream s2(str.substr(8,16));
    if (!(s2 >> std::hex >> $1.raw[1])) {
      $1.raw[1]=0;
    }
  // TODO: check that these really worked!
}
```

This could use a bunch more error handling still.

I tested these with:

```
%module test

%{
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream> //for testing
%}

// Typemaps go here

%inline {
struct my_128 {
    u_int64_t raw[2];
};

my_128 create() {
  const my_128 r = {0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef};
  return r;
}

void display (my_128 in) {
  std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << in.raw[0]
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << in.raw[1] << std::endl;
}
}
```

Which from a quick initial test gives:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.create()
16045690984833335023L
>>> test.display(16045690984833335023L)
deadbeefdeadbeef
>>> test.display(test.create())
deadbeefdeadbeef
>>> test.display(test.create()+1)
deadbeefdeadbef0
>>> test.display(test.create()+100)
deadbeefdeadbf53
>>> test.display(test.create()+10000000)
deadbeefdf46556f
>>> test.display(test.create()+100000000000000000000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: Expected at most a 128-bit int
>>> test.display(test.create()+100000000000000000)
e01104683c37beef
>>> test.display(test.create()+10000000000000)
deadc8082d205eef
>>>
```

Although it doesn't yet handle "shorter" integers properly because of the `substr()` calls.